# Use of fractional time signatures in Lilypond

Tags: time-signatures, lilypond, engraving

[image]

I am trying to recreate this time signature of 2 and a half over 4 in lilypond. I cannot figure out how to get the fraction in there, and for this project, I am required to keep as many engraving decisions the same as the manuscript, so I would rather do this than just write 5/8. Any advice?

Comment: How is that top line in time?

Comment: @Tim I'm afraid it simply is intended to mean *tremolo, until the the time is used up*.  The strange time signature and laziness in notation don't combine well here.

Comment: @guidot - thanks for that. But there's still 1/2 a 'beat' missing somewhere.  Sloppy.

Comment: Easy:  **DON'T DO THAT**  .  No musician wants to see that when a simple 5/8 signature could have been used.  Tell whomever said "keep same as manuscript" to stop being a fuddyduddy

Comment: @guidot Yes, I'm fairly certain it is just laziness. Unfortunately this is only a copyist's manuscript rather than the composer's original, so I cannot say for sure what the composer himself wrote there. I think I can safely assume that the composer did use (2 1/2)/4, as otherwise the copyist would not have changed it to something so strange, especially as 5/8 is used in other places, and there are several bars with blatantly wrong time signatures. Unfortunately the original manuscript has been lost, so unless it turns up somewhere this is the best I have.

Comment: @CarlWitthoft You may need to take that up with Percy Granger as well as the copyist/composer of this snippet.  I distinctly remember bars of 3½/8 and 1¾/4 in one of the movements my high school band skipped in _Lincolnshire Posy_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's some solution, but less than ideal. I'd prefer to use unicode for the 1/2 symbol, but the time signature font didn't seem to support it. I think you want some basic time signature as I've put (5/8) and then change the text of that, positioning the 1 and 2 in the 1/2 and drawing the line inbetween.

```
  myTwoAndHalfTimeSig = {
    \once \override Staff.TimeSignature.stencil = #ly:text-interface::print
    \once \override Staff.TimeSignature.text =
      \markup \override #'(baseline-skip . 0) \center-column \number {
        \concat  {"2" \magnify #0.5 \pad-x #-.2 {
                                   \translate #'(0 . 1) "1" 
                                   \translate #'(-1 . 0) \override #'(thickness . 2) \draw-line #'(1 . 2) 
                                   \translate #'(0 . 0) "2" }} "4" }
   \time 5/8}

right =  \relative c' {
  \myTwoAndHalfTimeSig
  c8 c c c c
}


left = \relative c {
  \myTwoAndHalfTimeSig
  c8 c c c c
}
```

[image]

Comment: Filed under "Not that you should, but you could"  :-)

Comment: This answer inspired me to make [a Lilypond function for creating arbitrary fractional time signatures](https://toouter.space/fraction.ly).  Should one of us consider editing the answer to work for fractions other than 2½/4?